# How to make all html elements top on a image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna make all my html element are top on the raindrop images,

Take the raindrop images as background, how to make it ?

DEMO => http://maroslaw.github.io/rainyday.js/demo012_1.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the `img` tag is required by **rainyday.js** you could add some custom JavaScript to show your contents in front of the screen. For this prepare your markup like below-

```
<body onload="run();" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <img id="background" alt="background" src="img/night.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container">
        Your contents goes here...
    </div>
    <canvas width="1920" height="705" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    </canvas>
</body>
```

When the image loads by rainday.js use this script to reveal your contents. Use **jQuery** to run this script only when page loads.

```
$(document).ready() {
    document.getElementById("background").remove();
    canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
    canvas[0].style.zIndex = -1;
});
```

What this snippet does is..

1. remove the `img` when page loaded because you don't need that on the page anymore.
2. set the `z-index` of canvas to `-1` so that contents can be viewable in front of the rainy screen.

Comment: No, i believe `remove` is native, at least in chrome. `'remove' in HTMLDivElement.prototype` => `true`

Comment: Yes, latest chrome and firefox support `remove`. IE still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

css may like this!

```
body {
    background: url(img/night.jpg) top center repeat;
}
```

In your html file, remove the  element!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the z-index attribute to accomplish what you want to do. For example, if you add `canvas { z-index: -1 }` to your css, it will layer all other elements above it.

Comment: Just want to add that the higher the z-index means it will be on top than others with low z-index. This might come in handy. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp